# Restarted Ubuntu 13.10 server, all connections refused. IPMI shows /bin /var /usr cannot be mounted (lvm2)

Tags: ubuntu, lvm

Upon boot on Ubuntu 13.10, IPMI is showing that it can't mount /tmp /usr /var folders, which are all setup as LV's. This results in the server refusing all connections via SSH or TCP.

I've hit a dead end with my attempts. Hosted on OVH, I can access rescue mode and mount volumes but can't seem to reset the root password because of how the old sysadmin setup the structure (or my inexperience).

I tried to mount /dev/md2 and chroot into it, but the "passwd" command doesn't work. md1 won't chroot, md5 has to be mounted via /dev/vg/home and so on because it's LV2 group.

With this limited info that I have, any ideas on how to reset root pass and then mount the stuff properly? do I need to mount md2 then mount the LV's inside of it?

Reason I ask how to reset pass first, is because upon boot it lets me Skip or Manual Mount, but manual mount requires root pass.

```
root@rescue:/# lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdb              8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk  
├─sdb4           8:20   0    1K  0 part  
├─sdb2           8:18   0  1.5G  0 part  
│ └─md2          9:2    0  1.5G  0 raid1 
├─sdb5           8:21   0  1.8T  0 part  
│ └─md5          9:5    0  1.8T  0 raid1 
│   ├─vg-usr   252:1    0  4.9G  0 lvm   
│   ├─vg-home  252:4    0  1.1T  0 lvm   
│   ├─vg-var   252:2    0  3.9G  0 lvm   
│   ├─vg-tmp   252:0    0  4.9G  0 lvm   
│   └─vg-mysql 252:3    0   16G  0 lvm   
├─sdb3           8:19   0  3.9G  0 part  
└─sdb1           8:17   0  259M  0 part  
  └─md1          9:1    0  259M  0 raid1
sda              8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk  
├─sda4           8:4    0    1K  0 part  
├─sda2           8:2    0  1.5G  0 part  
│ └─md2          9:2    0  1.5G  0 raid1
├─sda5           8:5    0  1.8T  0 part  
│ └─md5          9:5    0  1.8T  0 raid1 
│   ├─vg-usr   252:1    0  4.9G  0 lvm   
│   ├─vg-home  252:4    0  1.1T  0 lvm   
│   ├─vg-var   252:2    0  3.9G  0 lvm   
│   ├─vg-tmp   252:0    0  4.9G  0 lvm   
│   └─vg-mysql 252:3    0   16G  0 lvm   
├─sda3           8:3    0  3.9G  0 part  
└─sda1           8:1    0  259M  0 part  
  └─md1          9:1    0  259M  0 raid1
```

**fdisk -l**

```
Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        4096     534527     530432  259M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         534528    3604479    3069952  1.5G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3        3604480   11794431    8189952  3.9G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda4       11794432 3907018751 3895224320  1.8T  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       11796480 3907018751 3895222272  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a357f

Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *        4096     534527     530432  259M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2         534528    3604479    3069952  1.5G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3        3604480   11794431    8189952  3.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb4       11794432 3907018751 3895224320  1.8T  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       11796480 3907018751 3895222272  1.8T fd Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md5: 1.8 TiB, 1994353737728 bytes, 3895222144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/md2: 1.5 GiB, 1571749888 bytes, 3069824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/md1: 259 MiB, 271515648 bytes, 530304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/vg-tmp: 4.9 GiB, 5263851520 bytes, 10280960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/vg-usr: 4.9 GiB, 5238685696 bytes, 10231808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/vg-var: 3.9 GiB, 4190109696 bytes, 8183808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/vg-mysql: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/vg-home: 1.1 TiB, 1181116006400 bytes, 2306867200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: A simple trick once you have mounted /dev/md2 is to edit the `etc/shadow` file and to remove the encrypted password for root completely (the hash between the first and second `:`) , that will allow you to simply log on as root without a password and saves you the hassle of both getting your chroot and the passwd command to work.

Comment: @HBruijn that's awesome! I will give it a shot, thank you.

Comment: When you have rescued your system, the next step needs to be to update to something that isn't out of support for 4+ years ...